# Drag & Drop - Angular Material 2 Experimental CDK - Reordering Horizontally Stacked Items

Tags: angular, sass, angular5, angular-material2, angular-cdk

I am working with the brand new drag and drop functionality that was just added to the Angular Material Experimental CDK. I am trying to stack drag-able items horizontally but when I do so it breaks the drag and drop functionality. **Any ideas on what I am doing wrong?**

Here is my stackblitz: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-basic-horizontal-drag-drop

Comment: Figured this one out in another post: [https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12066](https://github.com/angular/material2/issues/12066)
Looks like this functionality is still a work in progress

Answer (score 0):

Those changes should solve your problem :
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-basic-horizontal-drag-drop-ghggjt?file=app/drag-drop-example.ts

I upgraded every libs to their latest version and edited HTML to follow latest official specifications.
( you can find them here : https://material.angular.io/cdk/drag-drop/overview )

New HTML now looks like this :

```
<div cdkDropList 
cdkDropListOrientation="horizontal" 
(cdkDropListDropped)="drop($event)" 
class="droplist">
<div *ngFor="let item of todo" cdkDrag>
  {{item}}
  <span class="drag-handle" cdkDragHandle >&#8596;</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: A link to a solution is welcome, but please ensure your answer is useful without it: [add context around the link](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/8259) so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there, then quote the most relevant part of the page you're linking to in case the target page is unavailable. [Answers that are little more than a link may be deleted.](//stackoverflow.com/help/deleted-answers)